# Fill only one textbox depending dropdown list selected value in Laravel vuejs Axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to autofill the textbox with only BadgeCode from databse  with the depending dropdownlist selected value. I’m very new at this. If anyone could help to get me out from this issue i’ll be very grateful. Thank You.

Here Is my HTML code

```
 <form @submit.prevent="editMode ? updateemployee() : createemployee()">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select
              name="company_id"
              id="company_id"
              :class="{'is-invalid':form.errors.has('company_id')}"
              class="form-control"
              v-model="form.company_id"
              @change="getEmployeesBadgeCode()"
            >
              <option value selected>Select Company</option>
              <option
                v-for="Company in Companies.data"
                :key="Company.id"
                :value="Company.id"
              >{{Company.Company}}</option>
            </select>
            <has-error :form="form" field="company_id"></has-error>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input
              v-model="form.BadgeCode"
              placeholder="Enter BadgeCode"
              type="text"
              name="BadgeCode"
              class="form-control"
              :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('BadgeCode') }"
            />
            <has-error :form="form" field="BadgeCode"></has-error>
          </div>
      </form>
```

My @change="getEmployeesBadgeCode" method:

```
methods: {
     getEmployeesBadgeCode: function() {
     axios.get("api/getBadgeCode", {
     params: { BadgeCode: this.form.BadgeCode}})
     .then( function(response) {this.employees = response.data;}.bind(this)
      );
     }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('getBadgeCode','API\EmployeeController@getBadgeCode');
```

My getBadgeCode(){} method:

```
    public function getBadgeCode(Request $request)
                              {$BadgeCode = Employee::where('BadgeCode',$request->BadgeCode)
                               ->orderBy('BadgeCode','desc')->get();  return ['data' => $BadgeCode]; 
                                   }
```

My data() in Vue Component:

```
data() {    
      return {      
               editMode: false,
              selectedTicketInvoiceId: false,
              Companies: {},

              Nationalities: {},
              employees: {},
              form: new Form({id: "",BadgeCode: "",BadgeType: "",company_id: "",
                               nationality_id: "",lastname: "",firstname: "",telphonenumber: "",
                               position: "",supervisorname: "", supervisornumber: "",
                               issuedate: "",tazker: "", expiredate: "", serialnumber: "" })};
 }
```

Comment: Can you console.log response.data and share result with us?
Any console error?

Comment: Could you do this: 
  getEmployeesBadgeCode: function() {
     axios.get("api/getBadgeCode", {
     params: { BadgeCode: this.form.BadgeCode}})
     .then( function(response) {t
his.employees = response.data;
console.log(response.data}.bind(this)
      );

So we can see what you get as response data.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending BedgeCode as a parameter but you should send company id as a parameter in order to get employees and their badge code. You basically try to get BadgeCode with BadgeCode. :) So it would look like something like this:

```
methods: {
     getEmployeesBadgeCode: function() {
     axios.get("api/getBadgeCode", {
     params: { company_id: this.form.company_id}})
     .then( function(response) {this.employees = response.data;}.bind(this)
      );
     }
```

You also need to modify getBadgeCode method on back-end:

```
public function getBadgeCode(Request $request)
{
    $Employees= Employee::where('company_id',$request->company_id)->orderBy('BadgeCode','desc')->get(); 

    return ['data' => $Employees]; 
}
```

So flow goes like this: You change Company, send request with company_id, get all Employees with that  company_id and get their BadgeCode. 
You can access particular employee BadgeCode as: this.employees[0].BadgeCode

Edit answer on question:

So define variable in your data, called BadgeCode:

```
data() {    
      return {      
              BadgeCode:"",
              editMode: false,
              selectedTicketInvoiceId: false,
              Companies: {},

              Nationalities: {},
              employees: {},
              form: new Form({id: "",BadgeCode: "",BadgeType: "",company_id: "",
                               nationality_id: "",lastname: "",firstname: "",telphonenumber: "",
                               position: "",supervisorname: "", supervisornumber: "",
                               issuedate: "",tazker: "", expiredate: "", serialnumber: "" })};
 }
```

Then assign value to it in your response function:

```
methods: {
     getEmployeesBadgeCode: function() {
     axios.get("api/getBadgeCode", {
     params: { BadgeCode: this.form.BadgeCode}})
     .then( function(response) {this.BadgeCode = response.data[0].BadgeCode;}.bind(this)
      );
     }
```

And set v-model in your input field to BadgeCode:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input
              v-model="BadgeCode"
              placeholder="Enter BadgeCode"
              type="text"
              name="BadgeCode"
              class="form-control"
              :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('BadgeCode') }"
            />
```

Comment: how I can show it in the input texbox field   can you explan it in code please how i can display it in the below code   <div class="form-group">
            <input
              v-model="form.BadgeCode"
              placeholder="Enter BadgeCode"
              type="text"
              name="BadgeCode"
              class="form-control"
              :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('BadgeCode') }"
            />
            <has-error :form="form" field="BadgeCode"></has-error>
          </div>

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'BadgeCode' of undefined
    at VueComponent.<anonymous>

Comment: can you now console.log(response.data) ?

Comment: Can you check if you have in your database BadgeCode column in Employees table? Also if you could dump response from your method getBadgeCode like this 
public function getBadgeCode(Request $request)
{
    $Employees= Employee::where('company_id',$request->company_id)->orderBy('BadgeCode','desc')->get(); 
dd($Employees); // it will print variable and stop executing here so we can see whats inside 
    return ['data' => $Employees]; 
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200401/discussion-between-n-djokic-and-mohammad-usman).

Comment: Collection {#303
  #items: []
}